# Calling of Method inside Helper function file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know about the `get()` method and how it's called in the helper. I haven't seen this method in controller.

Here is my helper code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');


function loginUser(){
  $CI = & get_instance();
  $sess = $CI->session->userdata('admin');
  $ar = unserialize($sess);
  $id=$ar['id'];
    $CI->load->model('admin_login_model');
  $details = $CI->admin_login_model->get($id);
 return $details->type;


}
?>
```

I want to know how  `$details = $CI->admin_login_model->get($id);` this method is called because the `get();` method does not find in controller

Comment: What do you mean by _"does not find in controller"_ - do you mean it errors, or you can't find that method?

Comment: I had to re-edit this over someone else's edit that wanted to remove the codeigniter tag; please don't do that and don't remove the relevant tags.

Comment: I can't find this method @thebluefox

Answer (score 0):

First of all
`$CI = & get_instance();` loads the CodeIgniter singleton instance which stores almost everything (helpers, libraries, etc.) in codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/ancillary_classes.html?highlight=instance#get_instance

Later `$CI->load->model('admin_login_model');` loads the `admin_login_model` model which is most likely stored in `application/models` directory as `admin_login_model.php`.
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html?highlight=loader#CI_Loader

It is loaded into the Codeigniter instance. In this example it is referenced by `$CI` using codeigniters syntax of `instance->model->function()`. Usually you use CI Instance with `$this` inside controllers for example.

Than you use the `get()` method of the `admin_login_model` model.

This method has nothing to do with any controller.

Comment: But there is no get() method inside admin_login_model Model @SEJBR

Comment: @Bhaveshverma and you dont get any errors like ```Call to undefined method admin_login_model::get()``` ? Do you have error reporting enabled? Add ```error_reporting(E_ALL);``` right after your opening <?php tag.